# Embeddings of complex projective Stiefel manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $k\leq n$ and define
\begin{align*}
V_k(\mathbb{C}^n) & =\{\textrm{orthogonal $k$-frames in } \mathbb{C}^n\}\\
& = \{A\in \textrm{Mat}_{n\times k}{(\mathbb{C})}\mid A^\ast A = {1}_k\}
\end{align*}
$V_k(\mathbb{C}^n)$ is a smooth (even real analytic) manifold called the Stiefel manifold of orthonormal $k$-frames in $\mathbb{C}^n$.

The complex torus $\mathbb{T}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid |{z}|=1\}$ acts on $V_k(\mathbb{C}^n)$. Hence I can define the projective Stiefel manifold:
$$
PV_k(\mathbb{C}^n)= V_k(\mathbb{C}^n)/\sim
$$

I am interested in the embeddings:
$$
PV_k(\mathbb{C}^n) \to \mathbb{R}^d
$$
**My question is:** given $n$ and $k$, is there any known result for the minimum value of $d$?

**Alternatively:** is there any result improving the value of $d$ given by Whitney embedding theorem?

Comment: Did you try to compute the normal Stiefel--Whitney classes?

Comment: Let me specify that I am not an expert in the field: I hit in the problem while looking at a completely different one. Since I am more familiar with harmonic analysis, I tried to tackle it in the particular case $n=k$. In this case the Stiefel manifold becomes the projective unitary group. It seems to me that standard techniques using principal orbits give bad embedding results (worse than Whitney). I was aware that computing Stiefel Whitney classes is another possibility, but since I am not an expert and it seems to me an hard problem, I was wondering if someone has already computed them.